# Outline a stroke isn't working in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to outline a stroke I created as a separate effect on some text in Illustrator but it isn't working. I wanted the stroke outside of the text so I had to create it as a separate effect and offset the path. Now I need to create outlines from the stroke so I can send it for vinyl plotting but that isn't working, nothing I try will convert the stroke to outlines. I've converted the text to outlines without issue. Here is the file:
[Illustrator File](https://misctemp.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/RacingNumber.ai)

If someone can help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems [to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSmGG.png) just fine here. It may help if you actually explain what "isn't working" means. Are you getting an error message? What *is* happening when you try?

Comment: If I open the layers panel I can see  the black eights have duplicate compound paths - there should only be two compound parhs, but there are in fact four. [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/zvVEyBI). Perhaps this is causing an issue? Try deleting two of them.

Comment: @Scott I can't seem to see or select the outlines, only the part that was the text. Might there be a setting I need to change to make the stroke outlines show up? Sorry, Illustrator noob here

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah I'm not seeing any of those in my file, no duplicates or strokes, just the two original 8's

Comment: I got it to work, had to ungroup the layers, delete the stroke and start over.

Comment: @Saeamous - you shouldn't have to ungroup anything to fix this. Perhaps you just need to open up the groups in the layers panel to see the different paths contained within the group.  Everything in Illustrator (or any vector image editor) is a separate object (a path). There should be no need start over here.  You might be confused because layers in raster software like Photoshop are different from the concept of layers in vector software.  In vector software, layers are really just groups of vector objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just jumping in here. I had a similar issue but found that it wasn't working due to the strokes being part of a compound path. First release the compound path then outline the strokes. Hopefully works for you.